# How to render html code from JavaScript on span tag of a jsp file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I am working on a jsp file, which has a span tag as shown below:

```
<span id="divBasicSearchResults" style="height:100%;"></span>
```

the Javascript file that renders html code on this span is shown below:

```
function renderBasicSearchNarrative1(response) {
var html = '';
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

if(response){
    html += '<table><tr><th colspan="5">Search Results</th></tr>';
    html += '<tr><td><b>#</b></td><td style="min-width:150px;"><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Lat/Long</b></td></tr>';
    html += '<tbody>';

    for(var i =0; i < response.length; i++){
        var result = response[i];
        var resultNum = i+1;            
        if(result.lat>47.33 && result.lat<48.92 && result.lon>9.8 && result.lon<13.46){ //this loop is to restrict the results to Munich
        html += "<tr valign=\"top\">";
        html += "<td>" + resultNum + "</td>";

        html += "<td>";
        if(result.display_name){
            var new_display_name = result.display_name.replace(/,/g, ",<br />");
            html += new_display_name;               
        }
        html += "</td>";

        html += "<td>" + result.lat + ", " + result.lon + "</td>";
        addmarker(result.lat, result.lon, "map-pointer-icon.png");

        html += "</tr>";
    } //end of for loop for Munich
}
    html += '</tbody></table>';
}

document.getElementById('divBasicSearchResults').style.display = "";
document.getElementById('divBasicSearchResults').innerHTML = html;
```

Now, in this above code I am generating an html code dynamically which is supposed to be rendered on the jsp file. But the problem which I am facing that I cannot see the whole html code which is dynamically generated, instead I just see the header data of the html code on my span tag. The result which I see on the span tag is:

```
Search Results
#Name   Lat/Long
```

Thanks in advance for reading this text, waiting for suggestions.

Comment: Have you added in some logging to check what you are getting back in your response?

Comment: Yes I have used console.log(html) and I am getting the required html code. But I cannot render it on the span tag!

Comment: What is the span sitting inside? The most likely cause is that it has a parent element with a fixed height and overflow hidden....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the height of your span. You need to check the css settings of the span parent elements. e.g. do they have a fixed height and overflow:hidden set on them. This would mean that your html is rendering perfectly within your span but just isn't being seen because there isn't enough space.

Also, as Eric points out, it is not correct mark-up to put a table inside a span. You should be using a div.

Comment: overflow:hidden should have been removed from the parent tag, this was the solution. Thanks allot guys for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest SPAN tag is not really appropriate to render a whole table : better use a DIV

Comment: Same issue with DIV as well. Moreover, when I put the whole code manually in the span tag, it is rendering the whole table as I need it to do. But it doesn't work when I try to do as show in the above question!

Comment: I would try to replace the span content with a simple multi-lines string, just to check that it has nothing to do with the content itself.